# Does "display:none" render the control ineffective?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, visibility

I am using a CMS for my site and im trying to alter the Skin of one module in the CMS.

I do not have the source code of the module. Only the skin where i can only modify the way the components are seen by changing the CSS.

I have a Radio Button list on the module which i want to disable or rather hide. In other words I want the chosen value to be '`option 3`' and dont want the end user to see this option available to him.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblist1" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden">
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 1" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 2" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 3" Value="1" Selected="True"/>
    <asp:ListItem Text="option 4" Value="4" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to user 'display:none' instead of 'visbility:hidden'. Will this cause an error in code? Or will the tag be rendered and take the default value 'option 3'???

Comment: Why ask us instead of just trying it yourself? It won't take more than a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use either `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, the value of the input won't be submitted with the form.  If you are trying to hide it, you should use

```
position:fixed; left:100%; top:100%;
```